# How to calculate the data in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to calculate the amount of the database column?

```
ID  -  Name   -   Quantity   -   Price -
1 ----- A ---------- 2 ---------- 200
2 ----- B ---------- 3 ---------- 150 
3 ----- C ---------- 5 ---------- 30 
4 ----- D ---------- 7 ---------- 10
5 ----- E ---------- 9 ---------- 10
```

**price** for one item, so i want like this **quantity x price = total** and **total** form **name**, totalized again. To be like this:

```
2 x 200 = 400
3 x 150 = 450
5 x 30 = 150
7 x 10 = 70
9 x 10 = 90
------------- +
TOTAL ???
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more information? What database are you using? (Are you using MySQL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a SQL database, you can perform a query such as

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * price) FROM products
```

if all you need is the sum of all products' `quantity * price`.

If you need the total price for each row, you can also do

```
SELECT products.*, (quantity * price) totalPrice FROM products
```

to get the individual data for each row with its `totalPrice` included.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, you could use a query similar to this:

```
SELECT *, (`Price` * `Quantity`) as `total_price` FROM `products`
```

That will get you a result set that looks like this:

```
  ID - Name - Quantity - Price - total_price
  1 -- A ---      2 ---   200 --- 400
  2 -- B ---      3 ---   150 --- 450
  3 -- C ---      5 ---    30 --- 150
  4 -- D ---      7 ---    10 --- 70
  5 -- E ---      9 ---    10 --- 90
```

Then you can use the [`SUM()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to calculate all of the totals together:

```
SELECT SUM(`Price` * `Quantity`) as `total` FROM `products`
```

Which will return a result set that looks like this:

```
total
 2230
```